# No module named

Tags: python

I have a python project with this structure: (This is not a real project, only for testing)

```
ImportTest
    ImportPersonsTest\
        ImportPerson\
            ImportPerson.py
        RunImportPersonTest.py
    RunImportTests.py
```

I want this tests to call each other. E.g :
RunImportTests.py calls a method in RunImportPersonTest.py, and RunImportPersonTest.py calls a method ImportPerson.py

RunImportPersonTest:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + "../../../")
from ImportPerson import ImportPerson
```

RunImportTests

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + "../../")
from ImportPersonsTest import RunImportsPersonTest
```

I have success when I run ImportPerson.py and RunImportPersonTest.py, but when I try to run RunImportTests I get this error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx\LiClipse Workspace\SystemTest\ImportTest\RunImportTests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ImportPersonsTest import RunImportsPersonTest
  File "xxx\LiClipse Workspace\SystemTest\ImportTest\ImportPersonsTest\RunImportsPersonTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ImportPerson import ImportPerson
ImportError: No module named 'ImportPerson'
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

New Structure

```
ImportTest
        ImportPersonsTest\
            ImportPerson\
                ImportPerson.py
                __init__.py
            RunImportPersonTest.py
            __init__.py
        RunImportTests.py
        __init__.py
```

Comment: Do you `__init__.py's` in the directories?'

Comment: Modules don't generally have capital letters in them

Comment: No, I didn`t Padraic, but I've added them now

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't have any `__init__.py` files in your project. Python needs those files to be able to import modules from folders. The good news is, they are very easy to make: most of the time, they don't need anything in them, they just have to exist.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Ok, so I've added init files in every directory, still doesn`t work, anything else I am missing? I will read docs tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of os.getcwd() is flawed.

My guess is that you're running your program from the ImportTest directory and so your current working directory will already allow you to do the first import without any need to fix up your path.  When you then try the second import, adding ".../ImportTest/../../.." or ".../ImportTest/../.." isn't helping Python find it.

To fix it either add the ImportPersonsTest directory to your path or use a suitably modified name in the import (ensuring you have your **init** files as already flagged) - e.g.

```
from ImportPersonsTest.ImportPerson import ImportPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two basic problem:

1. `os.getcwd()` as other `os` functions return path with no separator at the end. In fact you insert `xxx\LiClipse Workspace\SystemTest\ImportTest../../../` **which is not a valid path**
2. As mention by @peter, using os.getcwd() is bad idea - it's depend on your location when you run the script. Use:
   `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))` (`insert` recommend only at special cases)

But,

It seems that none of this caused your problem. It's only insert bad stuff to your `sys.path`. Your importing need to work good cause all the importing done from the self-module-dir, where python firstly search for the requested module.

I copy your package to mine machine - and both runs well!
I fix one spelling bug (RunImport**s**PersonTest -- RunImportPersonTest) - maybe there is other spelling problem